# What version of SharePoint am I running?

Tags: windows-server-2003, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

A server I've recently taken charge of has a copy of SharePoint installed.  Add or Remove Programs shows "Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007".

How do I find out if I'm running Standard, Enterprise or something else?

Additional facts:

- The server is running Windows Server 2003.
- The version hasn't been documented anywhere and there's nobody I can ask

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Central Admin -> Operations -> Convert License Type and the current license should be shown there.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to know the patching level of SharePoint on that server too:
http://msfarmer.blogspot.com/2009/07/sharepoint-versions.html

There are more version listings around, this one just to get you started.